# ExtJS - row renderer - if cell has certain value, highlight entire row

Tags: html, extjs

If the column cell value is > 5000, I want to highlight that entire row. Right now I am only able to highlight that cell.

Grid column renderer:

```
renderer:function(val_, meta_, rec_) {
  if(val_> 5000) {
     meta_.style = "background-color:red;"; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set [`getRowClass`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getRowClass) (on your grid) instead of the column renderer:

> Override this function to apply custom CSS classes to rows during
>   rendering. This function should return the CSS class name (or empty
>   string '' for none) that will be added to the row's wrapping element.

For example:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
        return record.get("someField") > 5000 ? "row-highlight" : "";
    }
}
```

Comment: any way of doing this directly in the code without relying on CSS?

Comment: Is there a way to do that dynamically like a renderer allows, so that if the content of the line changes, the color of the line changes ? The getRowClass function seems like it's not called as often as I would like.

Comment: You can see it is called in the `renderRow` method: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/src/Table.js-1.html#Ext.view.Table-method-getRowClass